# Flash - Fastest MySQL Connection

Tags: mysql, flash

Is there any way to create a "fast" connection between mysql and Flash that is still "secure"?

I'm playing around with a game that would allow players to move in 2d space around a tiled "world".  I'd like to show other players that are also playing on the screen at the same time, and have them be able to talk each other by hitting the space bar when you are close to them.  For this I would need something relatively quick (maybe 300-500ms?)  so when you hit space bar to talk to a guy that looks next to you, he isn't really half a screen away already.

I've looked at AMFPHP for this...but it seems like it would not be fast enough..

Thanks for the Help

Comment: 500ms should be easy enough. Where are you seeing the delay? _btw: amfphp isn't supported anymore. zend amf is the choice now._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at [Red5](http://trac.red5.org/): faster than AMFPHP and a good bit more capable.

Direct connections to MySQL are possible, but haven't seen those widely deployed. [AS-SQL](http://code.google.com/p/assql/) appears to provide support for it, but there is some policy file work you need to do to make it work reliably and that might be a bit of a pain.

Comment: Does anyone know if Red5 would be fast enough?  Or am I looking for something that just is not possible?

Comment: Red5 uses standard network connections and Java on the backend: if you have a fast enough network connection and don't do anything ridiculous in the server side java code there is no structural reason why it wouldn't be fast enough.